# What is the Java version that the Flink can support in 2022?

Tags: java, apache-flink

Let's say if I start a new Flink Java project, and if I look for "stable Flink Java production experience", which version should I need to use? The official [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/flinkdev/building/) says that it can support Java-11 starting from Flink 1.10 but a lot of users are still using Java-8, so trying to understand whether I need to use `AdoptOpenJDK-8` or `AdoptOpenJDK-11`.

Comment: If you start a new project: why do you care whether other users a still using Java 8 or not? Java 11 was released in 2018 and has proven to be stable. Why should you want to use Java 8 which was released in 2014 (eight years ago) ? (BTW not your downvoter)

Comment: My concern is - how much mature whether the Flink is with Java 11. Let's say if there is no much usage with Java 11 for the Flink then there is more possibilities for the bug in production with Flink. So I would like to understand how others are experiencing Flink with Java 11 (as Flink 1.10 is something released recently).

Comment: _as Flink 1.10 is something released recently_: that depends on how you define "recently" - Flink 1.10 was released on Feb. 11, 2020 which is two years ago. The most current stable version is Flink 1.14 which was released on Sep. 29, 2021 (with the latest patch release 1.14.4 released on Mar. 11, 2022) and they will probably soon release version 1.15. Version 1.15 will drop support for Java 8. The maintainers of Flink seem pretty convinced that Java 11 is the way to go.

Comment: Where did you find this `The maintainers of Flink seem pretty convinced that Java 11 is the way to go`? Perhaps from their documentation? If so, could you please point me to the docs?

Comment: **Point 1**: the upcoming release 1.15 (which I expect in the next days) requires [Java 11 to build it](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/flinkdev/building/) and requires [Java 11 to run it](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15//docs/try-flink/local_installation/) - Java 8 is no longer supported in this newest release. **Point 2**: if you look at the [roadmap](https://flink.apache.org/roadmap.html) they mark Java 11 as "stable" (not "Beta", not "Production ready & evolving", it is "stable") and Java 8 as "deprecated".

Comment: Their description for the stages are: "Stable: Unrestricted use in production", "Deprecated: Start looking for alternatives now". Do you really want to start a new project with a technology where the maintainers tell you that you should "Start looking for alternatives now"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both Java 8 and Java 11 are supported (though Java 8 has been deprecated).

Working toward support for Java 17 is happening under [FLINK-15736](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15736).

Update: Flink 1.18 added experimental support for Java 17, and experimental support for Java 21 is now in master and should be released with Flink 1.19.

Comment: Will I be able to use 'the latest and greatest', i.e. currently Java 18?

Comment: The focus has always been on Java versions with long-term support, so I would look for a Flink release with Java 17 support as the next major milestone. You can track progress towards this objective at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-15736.

Comment: Java 17 in now supported!

Comment: And Java 21 support is already in the master branch!