# Why does Flink require JDK 11 to compile the source code while its source/target is 1.8?

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink

I noticed that [Flink Doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/flinkdev/building/) says:

> Flink requires at least Java 11 to build.

On the other hand, the [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/pom.xml) specifies the source/target is 1.8:

```xml
<target.java.version>1.8</target.java.version>
...
    <source>${target.java.version}</source>
    <target>${target.java.version}</target>
...
```

My question is: why does Flink require a higher JDK than its `pom` specification?

---

## Update

I tried to build Flink from source in my computer with Java 8, and it succeeded! The statement "*Flink requires at least Java 11 to build.*" does not really make sense, except for the reason that higher JDK may bring better performance when building (but I didn't verify this yet).

The `java -version` is OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.342.07.1 (build 25.342-b07, mixed mode).

Comment: *"why does Flink require a higher JDK than its pom specification?"* - isn't it because it specifically uses stuff that only java 11 had? afaik, even if you tell the pom to use java 1.8, any library or maven plugin that require higher java may not work. you should seek [older flink (pre 1.15) for java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951793/what-is-the-java-version-that-the-flink-can-support-in-2022). java 8 and older are generally deprecated nowadays.

Comment: Difference between runtime and buildtime... the build requires higher JDK

Comment: @khmarbaise can you detail it? If the target/source here is 1.8, the source code is based on 1.8 language level. In which cases, a higher JDK is necessary for building?

Comment: @BagusTesa Java 8 is not deprecated. It's LTS for another 7 years.

Comment: @Michael the java, sure. the library that using it? not much, most (at least that i knew of) are in favor moving to the newer java.

Comment: @BagusTesa That's not the meaning of the word 'deprecated'. Deprecation is a specific thing.

Comment: `or maven plugin that require higher java may not work` which Maven plugin? Do you have errors during the build? Please post the log output if something is going wrong...That also the case if you have issues during the build which might be caused by other dependencies which might not being compiled for JDK8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation was intentionally changed before the actual code requirement to make sure that new devs start with Java 11, as that change will "soon" be required.

Source: [this comment on the Flink ticket to change the default in pom.xml to Java 11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-30501?focusedCommentId=17676061&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17676061), found by navigating the tickets linked to from [the commit that changed the text in the docs](https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/e9f0aaae3bb8fde5b31828167d67f367d0cf2a6e):

> That Flink does build with Java 8 was hidden from the docs since the deprecation of Java 8 support, so that new developers start developing with Java 11 from the get go.

Comment: Thanks. So, the real reason is that, the developers want to discard Java 8, while the Java 8 is still supported.  In fact, the movement to discard Java 8 is still on the way, because the master branch (1.18-SNAPSHOT) still uses it.

Comment: Knowing only what I read in the tickets, I think you're right: The plan is to move to Java 11 and it already works. They want to discourage new devs who get into the project to use Java 8 and thus "hide" that it still works with (and is in fact released/built using) Java 8. (Note that the page you linked is about *developing flink itself*, but [the page relevant to *using* flink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/configuration/gradle/) also mentions Java 11. I'd classify running recent versions on Java 8 as "working, but not officially supported".

Comment: I got your point. But if the pom still specifies target/source to 8, then new devs can never leverage the new language features in Java 11. I'd say their movement now can be only found in doc, rather than in code.

Comment: That is correct. They will need to wait for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-30501 to be implemented (or alternatively work on a branch where they do that manually with all the drawbacks that this involves).

Comment: Given that the latest Flink 1.17 still supports Java 8, and there should be explicit notice of Java 8 deprecation before Flink eventually make this backward incomptiable change, we should mark Java 8 as deprecated instead of making the incorrect statement that "Fink requires at least Java 11 to build". The doc has been updated to "Flink requires Java 8 (deprecated) or Java 11 to build" to address this issue. More context is provided in FLINK-30501 description.